# Prove $\mathcal T∘\mathcal R=\mathcal T∘\mathcal S$ for any $\mathcal T$ iff $\mathcal R∘\mathcal T=\mathcal S∘\mathcal T$ for any $\mathcal T$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, relations, alternative-proof

I am trying to understand if for two binary relations $\mathcal R$ and $\mathcal S$ the following statements are equivalent.

1. $\mathcal R=\mathcal S$
2. $\mathcal R\circ\mathcal T=\mathcal S\circ\mathcal T$ for any (possible) relation $\mathcal T$
3. $\mathcal R[X]=\mathcal S[X]$ for any (possible) $X$
4. $\mathcal R^{-1}=\mathcal S^{-1}$
5. $\mathcal T\circ\mathcal R=\mathcal T\circ\mathcal S$ for any (possible) relation $\mathcal T$

So if $1$ holds then trivially $2$ holds.

Now if $2$ holds then for any $X$ we can consider the identity relation $\operatorname{id}_X$ so that the equality
$$
\tag{2.1}\label{2.1}\mathcal R\circ\operatorname{id}_X=\mathcal S\circ\operatorname{id}_X
$$
holds. So by \eqref{2.1} we argue that the equality
$$
\mathcal R[X]=\mathcal R\big[\operatorname{id}_X[X]\big]=(\mathcal R\circ\operatorname{id}_X)[X]=(\mathcal S\circ\operatorname{id}_X)[X]=\mathcal S\big[\operatorname{id}_X[X]\big]=\mathcal S[X]
$$
holds.

Now if $(y,x)$ is in $\mathcal R^{-1}$ then $(x,y)$ is in $\mathcal R$ and so $y$ is in $\mathcal R[x]$; however, if by hypothesis the equality
$$
\mathcal R[x]=\mathcal S[x]
$$
holds then $y$ is in $\mathcal S[x]$ and thus $(x,y)$ is in $\mathcal S$: we conclude that $(y,x)$ is in $\mathcal S^{-1}$ which is in particular not empty. Moreover by analogous arguments we can see that if $\mathcal S^{-1}$ is not empty then even $\mathcal R^{-1}$ is not empty and in particular it contains $\mathcal S^{-1}$. So by extensionality we conclude that $\mathcal R^{-1}$ and $\mathcal S^{-1}$ are equals.

Now if $\mathcal R^{-1}$ and $\mathcal S^{-1}$ are equals then the equality
$$
\mathcal R^{-1}\circ\mathcal T^{-1}=\mathcal S^{-1}\circ\mathcal T^{-1}
$$
holds so that even the equality
$$
\mathcal T\circ\mathcal R=\big((\mathcal T\circ\mathcal R)^{-1}\big)^{-1}=(\mathcal R^{-1}\circ\mathcal T^{-1})^{-1}=(\mathcal S^{-1}\circ\mathcal T^{-1})^{-1}=\big((\mathcal T\circ\mathcal S)^{-1}\big)^{-1}=\mathcal T\circ\mathcal S
$$
holds.

Finally if 5. holds then the equality
$$
\mathcal T^{-1}\circ\mathcal R=\mathcal T^{-1}\circ\mathcal S
$$
holds so that as above it is not complicate to conclude that the equality
$$
\mathcal S^{-1}\circ\mathcal T=\mathcal R^{-1}\circ\mathcal T
$$
holds. So as in 2. we conclude that
$$
\mathcal R^{-1}[X]=\mathcal S^{-1}[X]
$$
for any set $X$. Finally as in $3$ we conclude that
$$
\mathcal R=\mathcal S
$$

So first of all I ask if actually statements 1-5 are equivalent and so I ask if I well proved it. Specifically I ask to prove it more using a more clear argument since it seems to me it would be better to prove $1\to 5\to 2\to 3\to 4\to 1$ but unfortunately I am not able to prove $5\to 2$. So couls someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution could be the following which use the following theorem.

> **Theorem** 1
>
> If $\mathcal R$ and $\mathcal S$ are two binary relations then the following statements are equivalent.
>
> 1. $\mathcal R\subseteq\mathcal S$;
> 2. $\mathcal R\circ\mathcal T\subseteq\mathcal S\circ\mathcal T$ for any binary relation $\mathcal T$;
> 3. $\mathcal R[X]\subseteq\mathcal S[X]$ for any binary relation $\mathcal T$;
> 4. $\mathcal R^{-1}\subseteq\mathcal S^{-1}$.

> *Proof*.

> ($1\Rightarrow 2$) So if $(x,y)$ is in $\mathcal R\circ\mathcal T$ then there exists $a$ such that $(x,a)$ is in $\mathcal T$ and $(a,y)$ in $\mathcal R$ but $\mathcal R$ is contained into $\mathcal S$ and thus $(x,a)$ is in $\mathcal T$ and $(a,y)$ in $\mathcal S$: we conclude that $(x,y)$ is in $\mathcal S\circ\mathcal T$.
>
> ($2\Rightarrow 3$) So if $\mathcal R\circ\mathcal T$ is contained for any relation $\mathcal T$ into $\mathcal S\circ\mathcal T$ then $\mathcal R\circ\operatorname{id}_X$ is contained into $\mathcal S\circ\operatorname{id}_X$. Now if $y$ is in $\mathcal R[X]$ then there exists $x$ in $X$ such that $(x,y)$ is in $\mathcal R$ but $(x,x)$ is in $\operatorname{id}_X$ so that $(x,y)$ is in $\mathcal R\circ\operatorname{id}_X$ and so in $\mathcal S\circ\operatorname{id}_X$: we conclude that $(x,y)$ is in $\mathcal S$ and so $y$ is in $\mathcal S[X]$ since by hypothesis $x$ is in $X$.
>
> ($3\Rightarrow 4$) So if $(y,x)$ is in $\mathcal R^{-1}$ then $(x,y)$ is in $\mathcal R$ so that $y$ is in $\mathcal R\big[\{x\}\big]$ which by hypothesis is contained into $\mathcal S\big[\{x\}\big]$: we conclude that $y$ is in $\mathcal S\big[\{x\}\big]$ so that there exists $x_*$ in $\{x\}$ such that $(x_*,y)$ is in $\mathcal S$ but $x_*$ must be necessarly $x$ and so $(y,x)$ is in $\mathcal S^{-1}$ since $(x_*,y)=(x,y)$ is in $\mathcal S$.
>
> ($4\Rightarrow 1$) So if $(x,y)$ is in $\mathcal R$ then $(y,x)$ is in $\mathcal R^{-1}$ and so in $\mathcal S^{-1}$: we conclude that $(x,y)$ is in $\mathcal S$.

So let's we prove the following corollary

> **Corollary** 2
>
> If $\mathcal R$ and $\mathcal S$ are two binary relations then the inclusion
> $$
> \mathcal R\subseteq\mathcal S
> $$
> holds if and only if the inclusion
> $$
> \mathcal T\circ\mathcal R\subseteq\mathcal T\circ\mathcal S
> $$
> for any binary relation $\mathcal T$.
>
> *Proof*.
>
> If $\mathcal R$ is contained into $\mathcal S$ then $\mathcal R^{-1}$ is contained into $\mathcal S^{-1}$ so that by thm. 1 the inclusion
> $$
> \mathcal R^{-1}\circ\mathcal T^{-1}\subseteq\mathcal S^{-1}\circ\mathcal T^{-1}
> $$
> holds. Now if $(x,y)$ is in $\mathcal T\circ\mathcal R$ then $(y,x)$ is in $(\mathcal T\circ\mathcal R)^{-1}=(\mathcal R^{-1}\circ\mathcal T^{-1})$ so that it is in $(\mathcal S^{-1}\circ\mathcal T^{-1})=(\mathcal T\circ\mathcal S)^{-1}$ and so $(x,y)$ is in $\mathcal T\circ\mathcal S$.
>
> Conversely if $\mathcal T\circ\mathcal R$ is contained into $\mathcal S\circ\mathcal R^{-1}$ then for any $\mathcal T$ then $\mathcal T^{-1}\circ\mathcal R$ is contained into $\mathcal T^{-1}\circ\mathcal R$ and so by thm. 1 the inclusion
> $$
> \mathcal R^{-1}\circ\mathcal T=(\mathcal T^{-1}\circ\mathcal R)^{-1}\subseteq(\mathcal T^{-1}\circ\mathcal S)^{-1}=\mathcal S^{-1}\circ\mathcal T
> $$
> holds: so by thm. 1 we conclude that $\mathcal R^{-1}$ is contained into $\mathcal S^{-1}$ and so $\mathcal R$ is contained into $\mathcal S$.

Now by extensionality a set $A$ is equal to a set $B$ iff $A$ is contained into $B$ and vice versa: so using thm. 1 and crl. 2 is possibile to prove the following theorem which actually is a corollary of thm. 1.

> **Theorem** 3
>
> If $\mathcal R$ and $\mathcal S$ are two binary relations then the following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\mathcal R=\mathcal S$;
> 2. $\mathcal T\circ\mathcal R=\mathcal T\circ\mathcal S$;
> 3. $\mathcal R\circ\mathcal T=\mathcal S\circ\mathcal T$ for any relation $\mathcal T$
> 4. $\mathcal R[X]=\mathcal S[X]$ for any set $X$;
> 5. $\mathcal R^{-1}=\mathcal S^{-1}$.

Comment: I haven't read through your Answer for accuracy, but this looks like a reasonable way to handle the slight awkwardness that you alluded to in the Question. Personally I would probably just show separately that each of 2-5 implies 1 (since the converse is obvious) without tying any of those proofs into each other, but the inverse trick you use here is also nice :)

Comment: Thanks for your opinion! ;-)